# Moving the mysql query out of the loop

Tags: php, mysql, high-load

i have the following code

```php
function cron_day_counts()
{
    $subids = get_subids();
    array_push($subids, '');
    $from = '2011-10-19';
    $to = '2011-10-20';
    $days = days_interval($from, $to);
    $result_array = array();
    foreach ($subids as $subid)
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $days; $i++)
        {
            $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($from . '+ ' . $i . ' day'));
            $date_prev = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . '- 1 day'));

            $unique_id_query = mysql_query('SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `id`,`subid`) FROM `tb_stats` WHERE `date` <= \'' . $date . '\'' . (!empty($subid) && is_numeric($subid) ? ' AND `subid` = \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($subid) . '\'' : '') . ') - (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `id`,`subid`) FROM `tb_stats` WHERE `date` <= \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($date_prev) . '\'' . (!empty($subid) && is_numeric($subid) ? ' AND `subid` = \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($subid) . '\'' : '') . ') AS `unique_ids`');
            $unique_id_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($unique_id_query);

            $total_id_query = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `id`,`subid`) AS `total_ids` FROM `tb_stats` WHERE `date` = \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($date) . '\'' . (!empty($subid) && is_numeric($subid) ? ' AND `subid` = \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($subid) . '\'' : ''));
            $total_id_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($total_id_query);

            $unique_ip_query = mysql_query('SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `ip`,`subid`) FROM `tb_stats` WHERE `date` <= \'' . $date . '\'' . (!empty($subid) && is_numeric($subid) ? ' AND `subid` = \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($subid) . '\'' : '') . ') - (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `ip`,`subid`) FROM `tb_stats` WHERE `date` <= \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($date_prev) . '\'' . (!empty($subid) && is_numeric($subid) ? ' AND `subid` = \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($subid) . '\'' : '') . ') AS `unique_ips`');
            $unique_ip_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($unique_ip_query);

            $total_ip_query = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `ip`,`subid`) AS `total_ips` FROM `tb_stats` WHERE `date` = \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($date) . '\'' . (!empty($subid) && is_numeric($subid) ? ' AND `subid` = \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($subid) . '\'' : ''));
            $total_ip_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($total_ip_query);

            $global_query = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `global` FROM `tb_stats` WHERE `date` = \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($date) . '\'' . (!empty($subid) && is_numeric($subid) ? ' AND `subid` = \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($subid) . '\'' : ''));
            $global_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($global_query);

            $result = array();
            $result['subid'] = $subid;
            $result['date'] = $date;
            $result['unique_ids'] = $unique_id_result['unique_ids'];
            $result['total_ids'] = $total_id_result['total_ids'];
            $result['unique_ips'] = $unique_ip_result['unique_ips'];
            $result['total_ips'] = $total_ip_result['total_ips'];
            $result['global'] = $global_result['global'];

            $result_array[] = $result;
        }

    }
    //db insert
    return $result_array;
}
```

I want to move all the query out of the foreach and for loops, I believe it would work faster. I'm stuck o this, having no idea how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say at the very least you should combine the queries in the loop to just one for each day. So for a 5 day range you would have 5 queries.

Or you could have a single query for the whole date range and move it outside the loop (as described by ajreal). Then use PHP to sort it all out.

For large databases I would rather split up queries a little to balance out the load and risk of timeouts. Also helps keep the code maintainable.

You should also look at how your database is structured and indexed.

Is it noticeably slow?

and is the array_push function necessary? (not that it would save much, just wondered cause it looks redundant)

If its really slow then maybe think about restructuring the process completely depending on how you use it.

You could, for example, at 00:01 each day do something like this:

- query the days log and count the unique/total IP/ID amounts
- insert just the count numbers and date in to a separate table
- archive the days log in to a separate archive table or even a separate db like [mongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)

This way you can perform simple querys to view the data and manipulate the numbers to your hearts content with good performance. And by archiving you're keeping the query table small by removing unecessary rows but maintaining a log if needed later.

Of course, this may not fit in with how your db is setup.

Comment: This function is not finished, i do this queries exactly to insert values to seperate table. It'll be executed each day via cron.

Comment: makes sense, could see at the end returns to a db but didn't know what for.

Comment: if this is executed daily why do you need a loop based on days? surely you can do away with a lot of that code and just query once?

Comment: If any problems will occur with the server and no query will be executed, the function will also perform "the day before query" or "three days before query" etc. I also indexed `date` and `subid` columns and now it works significantly faster. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

get all the `subid`

for each table,
build a single query to filter between the smallest date, and largest date,
and group by the date

```
select subid, `date`, count(*) ... 
where subid IN($subids) and `date` between $smallest and $largest
group by subid, `date`
```

iterate the result, and stored the result into array,  with subid, date as key

```
$mysql_results = array[$subid][$date] ...
```

lastly, iterate the $subids and date, like

```
foreach ($subids as $subid)
{
  for ($i = 0; $i < $days; $i++)
  {
     // set $date

     // check $mysql_results[$subid][$date] exists
  }
}
```

with something like above, you only required 5 queries instead of

```
5 x total days x size of the subids
```

Comment: Sounds perfect!!! i'll try to asjust your pattern to this query: "SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `id`,`subid`) FROM `tb_stats` WHERE `date` <= $date AND `subid` = $subid) - (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `id`,`subid`) FROM `tb_stats` WHERE `date` <= $date_prev AND `subid` = $subid) AS `unique_ids`"

Comment: Hmmm, i'n stuck again. I need to count (select count(distinct id,subid) where from tb_stats where subid in (...) and date between ... and ...) - (select count(distinct id,subid) where from tb_stats where subid in (...) and date between ... and ...) But this won't work, because i need to cound the amount of distinct id,subid where subid = ... and date = ... MINUS the amount of distinct id,subid where subid = ... and date = THE DAY BEFORE

Answer (score -1):

Take all of your `subids`, and do a fetch with an `IN` predicate to get all of the values at once. Stuff that in to an array, then loop the array.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. The problem is that I have also `date` column in WHERE clause, and it's dependent from the FOR loop.

Comment: You'll still need to loop the dates, as those are "changing" values, unless you want to create an array of those as well, and include them in another `IN` portion.

Comment: I have about 400,000 of records, i guess this will improve the perfomance significantly, am I right?(i mean moving the queries out of the loops). I also have another idea, to combine all the the queries into one, hoping to get even more perfomance. Tell me where I am wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Use  the PDO::MySQL extension instead of the MySQL or MySQLi extensions. This way, you can prepare the queries which will speed up considerably the execution time of the mysql calls.